# Is there any function to find if a value is an integer in R?

Tags: r

`if (x %% 1) == 0`
works for values like 1.2, 2.4 or 2.

But for values like 1.0, 2.0 this does not work.

Comment: You should use `x %% 1 == 0`.

Comment: @tmfmnk yes, sorry there was a typo error. ```x%%1 ==0``` works for all values like 1.2, 2.4 etc. however, for 1.0 or 2.0 it does not work.